# adb logcat: Increase the maximal message length

Tags: android, adb, logcat

it seems like logcat truncates very long log messages, is there a way to prevent this?

```
$ adb logcat -g
ring buffer is 64Kb (63Kb consumed), max entry is 20480b, max payload is 20460b
```

I think I need to increase the max entry and/or may payload size!?

Kind regards
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

max entry and max payload are harcoded as below. So i dont think you can change them.

> '#define LOGGER_ENTRY_MAX_LEN            (4*1024)
>   '#define LOGGER_ENTRY_MAX_PAYLOAD        \
>           (LOGGER_ENTRY_MAX_LEN - sizeof(struct logger_entry))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a custom class, which to you send your logmessages, which then divides them into multiple messages.  like:

```
MyLogger.d("LOG_TAG",veryLongMessage);
```

This class then just could check the size of the message, and split it up if nessecary, and then pass them into Log.d().